# Ubuntu `system search` another drive

Tags: 18.04, windows, search

One thing I like Ubuntu compared to other distro is it's capability to do [quick search](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/gs-use-system-search.html.en).

I've been looking for [`everything`](https://www.voidtools.com) (Windows tool) alternative for quite sometimes and it seems like this is the best at the moment.

However, this Ubuntu `system search` only search a local drive installed with the OS.

It doesn't search another physical drive.

Would it be possible to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu uses a local database for this. [locatedb](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/locatedb.5.html) is one version of this and it has a configuration file located at `/etc/updatedb.conf`.

Contents:

```
$ more  /etc/updatedb.conf
PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS="yes"
# PRUNENAMES=".git .bzr .hg .svn"
PRUNEPATHS="/tmp /var/spool /media /home/.ecryptfs /var/lib/schroot"
PRUNEFS="NFS nfs nfs4 rpc_pipefs afs binfmt_misc proc smbfs autofs iso9660 
ncpfs coda devpts ftpfs devfs mfs shfs sysfs cifs lustre tmpfs usbfs 
udf fuse.glusterfs fuse.sshfs curlftpfs ecryptfs fusesmb devtmpfs"
```

As you can tell for this lots of locations are not added to the indexing.

This is an example of a method to add a path when you use locatedb:

```
updatedb --localpaths '/ /media/usbdrive/dir/Music /media/usbdrive/dir/Photos'
```

---

I am not sure if needed but

```
sudo updatedb
```

will recreate the database by scanning your discs in case an alteration does not trigger it.

Answer (score 1):

Have your other drives and partitions auto-mounted in your `/etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p6 during installation
UUID=b40b3925-70ef-447f-923e-1b05467c00e7 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=D656-F2A8  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# Windows drives C, D & E
UUID=F2C2ACE4C2ACADF3 /mnt/e    ntfs-3g permissions,locale=en_US.utf8,x-gvfs-show   0       0
UUID=F03ED48E3ED44F6A /mnt/d    ntfs-3g permissions,locale=en_US.utf8               0       0
UUID=5CCC5867CC583E08 /mnt/c    ntfs-3g permissions,locale=en_US.utf8,x-gvfs-show   0       0
# Broken Ubuntu 16.04
UUID=f3f8e7bc-b337-4194-88b8-3a513f6be55b /mnt/old        ext4    x-gvfs-show       0       0
# Clone Ubuntu 18.04
UUID=8337e8c8-6461-44f2-b5fe-dfd5b6b05883 /mnt/clone      ext4    x-gvfs-show       0       0
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p9 during installation
UUID=b4512bc6-0ec8-4b17-9edd-88db0f031332 none            swap    sw                0       0
```

All of them will automatically be indexed for quick search. For example:

```
$ time locate .bashrc
/etc/bash.bashrc
/etc/skel/.bashrc
/home/rick/.bashrc
/home/rick/.bashrc~
/home/rick/restore/.bashrc
/home/rick/restore/.bashrc~
/mnt/clone/etc/bash.bashrc
/mnt/clone/etc/skel/.bashrc
/mnt/clone/home/rick/.bashrc
/mnt/clone/home/rick/.bashrc~
/mnt/clone/home/rick/eyesome/.bashrc
/mnt/clone/home/rick/restore/.bashrc
/mnt/clone/home/rick/restore/.bashrc~
/mnt/clone/usr/share/base-files/dot.bashrc
/mnt/clone/usr/share/doc/adduser/examples/adduser.local.conf.examples/bash.bashrc
/mnt/clone/usr/share/doc/adduser/examples/adduser.local.conf.examples/skel/dot.bashrc
/mnt/e/.bashrc
/mnt/e/Temporary Work/.bashrc
/mnt/old/etc/bash.bashrc
/mnt/old/etc/skel/.bashrc
/mnt/old/home/rick/.bashrc
/mnt/old/home/rick/.bashrc~
/mnt/old/usr/share/base-files/dot.bashrc
/mnt/old/usr/share/doc/adduser/examples/adduser.local.conf.examples/bash.bashrc
/mnt/old/usr/share/doc/adduser/examples/adduser.local.conf.examples/skel/dot.bashrc
/usr/share/base-files/dot.bashrc
/usr/share/doc/adduser/examples/adduser.local.conf.examples/bash.bashrc
/usr/share/doc/adduser/examples/adduser.local.conf.examples/skel/dot.bashrc

real    0m0.868s
user    0m0.852s
sys     0m0.017s
```

Even Windows files are indexed:

```
$ time locate /cmd.exe
/mnt/c/Windows/SysWOW64/cmd.exe
/mnt/c/Windows/SysWOW64/en-US/cmd.exe.mui
/mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe
/mnt/c/Windows/System32/en-US/cmd.exe.mui
/mnt/c/Windows/WinSxS/amd64_microsoft-windows-c..andprompt.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17134.1_en-us_65026a8ffb1498f6/cmd.exe.mui
/mnt/c/Windows/WinSxS/amd64_microsoft-windows-commandprompt_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17134.1_none_708d53148386ef59/cmd.exe
/mnt/c/Windows/WinSxS/wow64_microsoft-windows-c..andprompt.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17134.1_en-us_6f5714e22f755af1/cmd.exe.mui
/mnt/c/Windows/WinSxS/wow64_microsoft-windows-commandprompt_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17134.1_none_7ae1fd66b7e7b154/cmd.exe
/mnt/d/Windows/SysWOW64/cmd.exe
/mnt/d/Windows/SysWOW64/en-US/cmd.exe.mui
/mnt/d/Windows/System32/cmd.exe
/mnt/d/Windows/System32/en-US/cmd.exe.mui
/mnt/d/Windows/WinSxS/amd64_microsoft-windows-c..andprompt.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10586.0_en-us_0c0776913c41663d/cmd.exe.mui
/mnt/d/Windows/WinSxS/amd64_microsoft-windows-commandprompt_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10586.0_none_17925f15c4b3bca0/cmd.exe
/mnt/d/Windows/WinSxS/wow64_microsoft-windows-c..andprompt.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10586.0_en-us_165c20e370a22838/cmd.exe.mui
/mnt/d/Windows/WinSxS/wow64_microsoft-windows-commandprompt_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10586.0_none_21e70967f9147e9b/cmd.exe

real    0m0.989s
user    0m0.980s
sys     0m0.008s
```

I added the `time` command so you can see how it takes less than a second. For a count of all the files indexed use:

```
$ time locate * | wc -l
625125

real    0m39.088s
user    0m38.644s
sys     0m0.423s
```

It takes `39` seconds to list 625,125 file names and count them.